# bokeh server app returns blank screen

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to render a simple app on bokeh server. I took the script straight from the bokeh website.

```
# myapp.py

from random import random

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

# create a plot and style its properties
p = figure(x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 100), toolbar_location=None)
p.border_fill_color = 'black'
p.background_fill_color = 'black'
p.outline_line_color = None
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

# add a text renderer to our plot (no data yet)
r = p.text(x=[], y=[], text=[], text_color=[], text_font_size="20pt",
           text_baseline="middle", text_align="center")

i = 0

ds = r.data_source

# create a callback that will add a number in a random location
def callback():
    global i

    # BEST PRACTICE --- update .data in one step with a new dict
    new_data = dict()
    new_data['x'] = ds.data['x'] + [random()*70 + 15]
    new_data['y'] = ds.data['y'] + [random()*70 + 15]
    new_data['text_color'] = ds.data['text_color'] + [RdYlBu3[i%3]]
    new_data['text'] = ds.data['text'] + [str(i)]
    ds.data = new_data

    i = i + 1

# add a button widget and configure with the call back
button = Button(label="Press Me")
button.on_click(callback)

# put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document
curdoc().add_root(column(button, p))
```

I run this in my `Win Python Command Prompt.exe` using the below:

```
python -m bokeh serve --show main.py
```

This runs the app, but I am left with a blank webpage. See the output in the command prompt below:

[image]

Can anyone help with how to get this to show the doc?

Comment: It seems that your trying to execute the wrong python script : are you sure that you execute your command 'python -m bokeh serve --show main.py' in the directory containing your python script ? There are warnings about output_file() and show() that are not in your script...

Comment: If python window do not give you information about what's wrong, you may also have clues of what is not working right directly from the browser : -> F12 to get debug window, -> console to get javascript (including bokehJS) errors. It helped me sometimes..

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm not sure what the issue was, but it is now running the correct script.